# SphinxQL: sql_attr_multi unique GROUP BY

Tags: sphinxsearch, sphinxapi

Добрый день, использую SphinxQL после Java API и сталкиваюсь с некоторыми неприятностями.

Запрос на группировку различных опций для товаров.

```
SELECT option, COUNT(*) FROM books WHERE MATCH('" + key + "') GROUP BY option;
```

Результат:

```
option: 20,62, count: 34666
option: 20,62, count: 8309
option: 28, count: 313
```

API возвращал так и это круто. Как добиться такого же результата?

```
option: 62, count: 34666
option: 20, count: 8309
option: 28, count: 313
```

Ибо первый пример не дает возможности использовать айдишники опций.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Необходим @groupby и все будет как нужно.

```
SELECT @groupby AS shop..
```